# Configuracion de Jenv no se mantiene en la terminal

Tags: java, linux, linux-mint

Recientemente instale jEnv una herramienta de administracion de versiones de Java, segui los pasos de instalacion los cuales son super sencillos, sin embargo, cuando cierro y abro mi terminal, la configuracion desaparece y no reconoce los nuevos comandos.

[Guia de Instalacion](https://www.jenv.be/)

Analizando el problema, descubri que Linux Mint, maneja en lugar de `.bash_profile`, .profile, asi que modifique los comandos que dan de instalacion por `.profile`, sin embargo, tampoco se soluciono

Distribucion:

- OS: Linux Mint 21.3 x86_64
- Kernel: 5.15.0-101-generic